# required input type number up and down arrow hold to increment functionality for a span and input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, touch-event

How can we achieve input type number on tap hold increase value by 1 in mobile,

```
<input type="text" id="number" value="1">
<span id="upSpan"> Up </span>


$('#upSpan').on('touchstart', function(){ var value = $('#number').val(); $('number').val(value + 1);})
```

This need to be worked as input type number.

Answer (score 1):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/4fewN/

#### HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="number" value="1"/>
<span id="upSpan"> Up </span>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$('#upSpan').on('vclick', function(){ 
    var value = parseInt($('#number').val()); 
    $('#number').val(value + 1);
});
```

Comment: Hi @dand If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: you typed "dandif", I don't think he got that

Comment: thanks for reply, http://jsfiddle.net/NDJr2/ need this functionality working in mobile.